# Query for optimal pixel format when capturing video on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, avfoundation

The [AVFoundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188) states that the preferred pixel formats when capturing video are:

- for iPhone 4: `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` or `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`
- for iPhone 3G: `kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8` or `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`

(There are no recommendations [yet] for the iPhone 5 or for iPad devices with cameras.)

There is however no help provided as to how I should go about and determine what device the app is currently running on. And what if the preferred pixel format becomes different on a future and therefor to my app unknown device?

What is the correct, and future proof, way to determine the preferred YpCbCr pixel format for any device?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just set the video settings to nil and AVFoundation will use the most efficient format. For instance instead of doing

```
NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
videoOutput.videoSettings = videoSettings;
```

Do this instead

```
videoOutput.videoSettings = nil;
```

You may also try not setting it at all. I know in the past I would just set this to nil unless I needed to capture images in a specific format.

**edit**

To get the format AVFoundation chose to use.

```
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(source);
CGColorSpaceRef cref = CVImageBufferGetColorSpace(imageBuffer);
```

Comment: Yes that will give the most efficient format. But I want the most efficient format that is YpCbCr pixel format. Current implementations will yield this on both iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4, but is it future proof? The documentation to the public API:s does not say,

Comment: If you needed to check what the most efficient format is then you could set the video settings to nil and then check what format the CMSampledBufferRef is. I know this does not necessarily help you as you have to know what YpCbCR format is the most efficient.