# NSDictionary extra argument "forKey" in call

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

As my question states, I keep getting the error "extra argument 'forKey' in call" while trying to write this piece of code. Can someone please explain why?

```
var rgbOutputSettings:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: NSNumber(int: kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA), forKey: kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey` is a `CFStringRef` and not an `NSString`. You need to cast it to an `NSString`, like so:

```
var formatKey = kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString
var rgbOutputSettings:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: NSNumber(int: kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA), forKey: formatKey)
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you very much! I figured there was a casting issue in there somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Breaking down your statement we get:

```swift
let obj = NSNumber(integer: kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA)
let key = kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey
var rgbOutputSettings : NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: obj, forKey: key)
```

The problem is that `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey` can be of more that a single type. Quoting the documentation (emphasis mine):

> kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey:
>
> The pixel format for this buffer (type CFNumber, **or type CFArray** containing an array of CFNumber types (actually type OSType)).

I've converted into String to make it compile:

`let key: String = kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String`

Maybe that's not want you need, if you need to achieve something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191806/how-to-choose-the-a-pixel-format-type-kcvpixelbufferpixelformattypekey-for-use)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, "Extra argument in call" is given even if the call looks right, if the types of the arguments don't match that of the function declaration.

Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795035/swift-extra-argument-in-call) on SO

So you can use it as

var key = kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString